# In Actionscript 3, what happens if different events change the value of a variable at the same time?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables

What happens if two events that occur at the same time change the value of a variable?

For instance, we have two objects: `A` and `B`, loaded into the `stage` and a stage variable named `varx`.

The following code is embedded in `A`'s fifth frame:

```
stage.varx = 9
```

In the other hand, we have, in `B`'s fifth frame, the following code:

```
stage.varx = 2
```

So, what'll be `varx`'s value, when both MovieClips reach their fifth frame?

Comment: It's all run in one thread (so nothing happens at the same time really), so whichever frame executes last will prevail. Probably which ever of A or B is higher on the display list (eg Layer order).  Why don't you test it and find out?  If you do, test it a bunch of times to see if it's consistent.

Comment: You might encounter a set of events known as "race condition", in case your A and B have different frame rates, or change them in progress.  I'd say you should not allow this to ever happen as a matter of good practice, due to hard to find bugs in your code once you start employing such double stateless setting of a single variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

`A` and `B` won't enter the fifth frame at the same exact time, unless you're doing something fairly unusual.  Either `A` or `B` will get to it first, and whichever come last will overwrite the first one's value.  Just make sure you don't `depend` on them firing in a certain order.  Even you're doing something unusual, it's still basically a non-issue.

---

This is answered assuming that you're referring to a single program with multiple objects in the stage.  If you're talking about multiple programs trying to share some sort of global `stage` state instead (I'm not sure whether they would share the same `stage` object or not), then I can't say for sure, but it will most likely work the same way.

Flash *generally* does not use multi-threading.  In fact, AS3 did not suport it at all until maybe two years ago, give or take.  99% of the time, swfs simply will not use it.

In that case, `A` and `B` will not enter their fifth frames at the same time.  It's impossible.  One has to enter its fifth frame first, then the other.  It requires multithreading to change this fact within a single program.

So let's say you have event handlers that'll fire when each enters the fifth frame.  This is what will happen:

1. The first one to enter that frame will do so.
2. Then it will raise an event.
3. Then your handler for that object will catch that event.
4. Then your handler will set the `stage` variable to whatever value you gave for that particular handler.
5. *Then, once all that's done,* the other object will finally enter its fifth frame.

One thing about events in AS3 is they're not as closely tied to the central core of the language as you might expect when you first start out.  They're simply a class in the "usual API" that have had a part of that API built completely around them.  So when you handle an event, all that really happens is that some code suddenly decides that it wants to dispatch an event.  So then it creates an instance of class `Event`, then it calls one of its functions called `dispatchEvent`, passing in the `Event` as an argument.  Then `dispatchEvent` just looks through a list of callback functions and starts calling them one after another, passing the `Event` as an argument to each of them.  One of those callbacks is your event handler.  One callback is called *and returns*, then the next, then the next.  So whereas event-handling is asynchronous as a whole, the dispatching and handling of events is carried out in a basically synchronous manner.

The exception to the one-thing-at-a-time rule is when you use worker threads in more modern versions of Flash.  This actually may be a little closer multiprocessing than multithreading (arguably a blend of the two), as it actually requires the use of secondary, embedded swfs which communicate through the main swf through "workers".  So yes, you could perhaps run into a situation here where they both try to mess with the same variable at the same time.

This is a very common problem in computer science, but the short answer is this: Platforms that you program on top of, whether they're Flash or .NET or whatever, are generally designed to block you from being able to write to the *exact same* variable and/or memory address at the same exact time from two different sources.  Unless you decide to go much lower-level, you can generally assume that the platform will have its own locking mechanisms internally built in that will prevent simultaneous writes.  This almost certainly applies here.

However there are two caveats to this:

1. This applies to *one specific variable / memory address*.  It does not necessarily apply to, let's say, the internal state of an entire string.  A textbook problem with multithreading in a language like C++ is if two threads try to concatenate on the same exact string variable at the same exact time.  In C++, a string is quite literally an array of `chars` (or an instance `std::string`, which will a wrapper around this) that only ends when it gets to an element with integer value `0`.  So two threads trying to add characters to the string might start at slightly different times, with both starting before the first is finished, at which point the second thread will be changing the value of character `x` while the first is changing the value of character `x + y`.  In higher-level languages though, there are often safeguards that are built in specifically for the case of strings, but you can still run into this easily when multiple variables are changed within a given object.
2. Race conditions.  Vesper touched on this.  While `A` and `B` may not change `stage.x` at exactly the same time, you still don't quite know what order they're going to change it in.  And it will not be built into the platform, either in Flash or in most of anything else.  When you have anything that's asynchronous, even if it's just on the surface and in a single-threaded environment, you have to place logic there to make sure that other stuff is not dependent on it being executed in any particular order.

This generally holds with computer science in general.  You may already know most of this, but essentially the answer is that nothing unusual will happen to `stage.x`; it's just that you can't tell which value will come first or last.

Answer (score 0):

When  `A` reaches fifth frame `stage.varx` become `9`

`stage.varx = 9`

When  `B` reaches fifth frame `stage.varx` become `2`

`stage.varx = 2`

Let us assume that`A` come first and `B` ccomes second , then the value will be 2 , just like if we assign

`var i:int = 2;
var i:int = 3;
//output i = 3`

Simple as that